# On classes $AWPP$ and $APP$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

**(1)** $PP$ contains problems like 'is perm(M)>k'. So what problems does $AWPP$ and $APP$ contain with respect to permanent?

**(2)** Since it is not known if $NP$ is in $AWPP$ or $APP$ is there a candidate problem in $NP$ not in $AWPP$ and outside $NP$ complete problems? Or does $NP\cap AWPP = NP\backslash NPC$?

Comment: Now, (2) is also non sequitur.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am assuming no class contains $NP\backslash NPI\cup P$. Is this still not logical?

Comment: Do you mean $(NP\setminus NPI)\cup P$ or $NP\setminus(NPI\cup P)$? Either way, there are certainly classes that contain it, so why would you assume otherwise? How is any of this related to the problem whether it is possible for $\mathit{NP\cap AWPP}$ to equal $\mathit{NP\setminus NPC}$ (that is, $\mathit{NPI\cup P}$)?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I corrected post I am just looking for a problem outside P and inside NP which is outside AWPP. This should be possible.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39199/discussion-between-emil-jerabek-and-turbo